# Mock external library call using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

New to jest and react code testing.
I am testing a file which imports base64 from react-native-base64 and decodes a value that is fetched from backend system in useEffect. Below is the sample code.

```
import base64 from "react-native-base64";
 
  const xyzWork = async () => {
    const value = await - fetch data from backend
    const decodedValue = base64.decode(value);
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    xyzWork();
  }, []);


  return <div><SomeComponent /></div>;
```

I am facing difficulties while testing this code using jest.
I tried multiple ways to test the same but it is failing with multiple errors.

Some of the ways, import base64 same way and mock like this.
`base64.decode = jest.fn(()=> "testParsedValue");`

Tried to mock entire library itself like `const mockedLib = jest.mock("react-native-base64", () => jest.fn());` and then mock base64 of that variable but nothing seems working.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mock it using the [Jest module factory](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) e.g.

```
jest.mock('react-native-base64', () => ({
    decode: () => "testParsedValue"
}));
```